# How to make this very complicated query from three connected models with Django ORM?

Tags: sql, django, django-orm

Good day, everyone. Hope you're doing well. I'm a Django newbie, trying to learn the basics of RESTful development while helping in a small app project. We currently want some of our models to update accordingly based on the data we submit to them, by using the Django ORM and the fields that some of them share wih OneToMany relationsips. Currently, there's a really difficult query that I must do for one of my fields to update automatically given that filter. First, let me explain the models. This are not real, but a doppleganger that should work the same:

First we have a `Report` model that is a teacher's report of a student:

```
class Report(models.Model): 

    status = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=Statuses.choices, default=Statuses.created,)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    headroom_teacher = models.ForeignKey(TeacherStaff, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)

    # Various dates
    results_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    report_created = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    .
    #Other fields that don't matter
```

Here we have two related models, which are `student` and `headroom_teacher`.  It's not necessary to show their models, but their relationship with the next two models is really important. We also have an `Exams` model:

```
class Exams(models.Model):

    student = models.ForeignKey(student, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)     
    headroom_teacher = models.ForeignKey(TeacherStaff, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
            
    # Various dates
    results_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    initial_exam_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    .
    #Other fields that don't matter
```

As you can see, the purpose of this app is akin to reporting on the performance of students after  completing some exams, and every Report is made by a teacher for  specific student on how he did on those exams. Finally we have a final model called `StudentMood` that aims to show how should an student be feeling depending on the status of their exams:

```
class StudentMood(models.Model):

    report = models.ForeignKey(Report, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    student_status = models.CharField(
        max_length=32, choices=Status.choices,
        default=None, null=True, blank=False)
    headroom_teacher = models.ForeignKey(TeacherStaff, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
```

And with these three models is that we arrive to the crux of the issue. One of our possible `student_status` options is called `Anxious for results`, which we believe a student will feel during the time when he already has done an exam and is waiting for the results.

I want to automatically set my `student_status` to that, using a custom manager that takes into account the date that the report has been done or the day the data has been entered. I believe this can be done by making a query taking into account `initial_exam_date`.

I already have my custom manager set up, and the only thing missing is this query. I have no choice but to do it with Django's ORM. However, I've come up with an approximate raw SQL query, that I'm not sure if it's ok:

```
SELECT student_mood.id AS student_mood_id FROM
school_student_mood LEFT JOIN
school_reports report
ON student_mood.report_id = report.id AND student_mood.headroom_teacher_id = report.headroom_teacher_id
JOIN school_exams exams
ON report.headroom_teacher_id = exams.headroom_teacher_id 
AND report.student_id = exams.student_id
AND exams.results_date > date where the student_mood or report data is entered, I guess
```

And that's what I've come to ask for help. Could someone shed some light into how to transfer this into a single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having an environment setup or really knowing exactly what you want out of the data. This is a good start.

Generally speaking, the Django ORM is not great for these types of queries, and trying to use select_related or prefetches results in really complex and inefficient queries.

I've found the best way to achieve these types of queries in Django is to break each piece of your puzzle down into a query that returns a "list" of ids that you can then use in a subquery.

Then you keep working down until you have your final output

```py
from django.db.models import Subquery

# Grab the students of any exams where the result_date is greater than a specific date.
student_exam_subquery = Exam.objects.filter(
    results_date__gt=timezone.now()
).values_list('student__id', flat=True)

# Grab all the student moods related to reports that relate to our "exams" where the student is anxious
student_mood_subquery = StudentMood.objects.filter(
    student_status='anxious',
    reports__student__in=Subquery(student_exam_subquery)
).values_list('report__id', flat=True)

# Get the final list of students
Student.objects.values_list('id', flat=True).filter(
    reports__id__in=Subquery(student_mood_subquery)
)
```

Now I doubt this will work out of the box, but it's really to give you an understanding of how you might go about solving this in a way that is readable to future devs and the most efficient (db wise).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, I really appreciate it. I actually thought using subquerys would be more stressful for the database and had my mind set on a single magical query. I'll open my outlook now.

Comment: There is one issue with your answer, and is that the final sub-query should be a list of all students with a student mood of anxious, not the other way around. Maybe I'm misunderstanding your subquery, haven't used them before, is that the final result here?

Comment: @MIGUELALFONSOFIGUEROAANGULO - I'm reasonably confident that's what the query does. As the subquery which it uses to get a list of student ids  where the repots are "in" the list of reports linked to a student mood of anxious.

Comment: if you assign this query to a variable called "qs" you can always print("qs.query") to see the SQL it populates and fix from there.

Comment: @MIGUELALFONSOFIGUEROAANGULO did you end up getting this working?

Comment: I honestly haven't. But your answer was the only one I received so I gave it the check. Thank you

Comment: Damn - let me know if there is anything else I can do to get this sorted - don't like not solving something.

Comment: I'll make a new answer to show you what I have right now.

Comment: Trent, okk I made another comment with my progress. Check it out

Answer (score 0):

So, the issue I was running into, is that the school has exam cycles each period, and it was difficult to retrieve only the students' report for this cycle. Let's assume we have the following database:

```
+-----------+-----------+----------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+
|  Student  | Report ID | StudentMood ID | Exam Cycle Status | Initial Exam Date | Report created a |
+-----------+-----------+----------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+
| Student 1 |         1 |              1 | Done              | 01/01/2020        | 02/01/2020       |
| Student 2 |         2 |              2 | Done              | 01/01/2020        | 02/01/2020       |
| Student 1 |         3 |              3 | On Going          | 02/06/2020        | 01/01/2020       |
| Student 2 |         4 |              4 | On Going          | 02/06/2020        | 01/01/2020       |
+-----------+-----------+----------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+
```

And Obviously, I wanted to limit my query to just this cycle, like this:

```
+-----------+-----------+----------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+
|  Student  | Report ID | StudentMood ID | Exam Cycle Status | Initial Exam Date | Report created a |
+-----------+-----------+----------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+
| Student 1 |         3 |              3 | On Going          | 02/06/2020        | 01/01/2020       |
| Student 2 |         4 |              4 | On Going          | 02/06/2020        | 01/01/2020       |
+-----------+-----------+----------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+
```

Now, your answer, `trent`, was really useful, but I'm still having issues retrieving in the shape of the above:

```
qs_exams = Exams.objects.filter(initial_exam_date__gt=now()).values_list('student__id', flat=True)
qs_report = Report.objects.filter(student__id__in=qs_exams).values_list('id', flat=True)
qs_mood = StudentMood.objects.select_related('report') \
.filter(report__id__in=qs_report).order_by('report__student_id', '-created').distinct()
```

But this query is still giving me all the StudentMoods throughout the school year. Sooooo, any ideas?

Comment: Does your report have a link to exam? I can only see the head teacher being a link, but that's not strong enough to filter like you want. If Report is linked to an exam (or multiple), then you can filter reports only by exams that have an exam_cycle_status of "ongoing"

Comment: Oh I wished it did, believe me. It would make the query a very straightforward process, but since this is just a doppleganger of a real life model I have, I 'm not allowed to connect Exam to report, because the real model doesn't have that FK either. We have to assume that

Comment: thank you, but it.s still giving me a whole list of reports related to the student, even those of the last cycle. How exactly do you do a GROUP BY and MAX in django, anyways? I thought using distinct would do.

Comment: The problem is not max or distinct, it's because you don't have a great link between the exams and the reports (this is a pretty serious design flaw you're working with). Can you do a pg_dump of the data (I'm guessing its all just dummy data anyway)?

Comment: Sorry, this is all the data I have. The rest is real

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233529/discussion-between-trent-and-miguel-alfonso-figueroa-angulo).